# How can I show the resource usage of a Jupyter notebook in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Understand that there is a `jupyter-resource-usage` Jupyter extension which allows us to monitor the resource usage (e.g. CPU, memory) of a running Notebook (server and its children (kernels, terminals, etc)). Is there a similar feature available in VSCode?

(Alternatively, can we install such extensions in VSCode Jupyter?)